# TFS Azure website is down: Error persists after rollback

Tags: azure, tfs, rollback, changeset

I had a website connected with TFS and Azure.

I added another project to that solution and accidentally messed with its nuget packages.

Now I rolled back to the changeset that was before, and the solution in both VS and TFS online looks like that changeset that used to be before.

Anyway, the website is still down, I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/rsqpLh1n/) error:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, 
Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

<OLDPROJECTNAME!>.Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) +0
<OLDPROJECTNAME!>.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) +5
Which definitely belongs to the old added project which has now been removed 
from solution/changeset.
```

Why does TFS insist on complaining about a problem that doesn't exists in the changeset at all!

### Update

Another evidence that this is a misbehavior of the deployment process.
I've created a brand new website on azure and deployed the same website again and works like a charm.
The problem is I don't want to delete and recreate the website because I don't have access to the domain host and its settings.
Is there a way to clean an azure website's contents (but the domain settings) and redeploy it?

Comment: Doubt it's related, but be aware of Azure outages at the moment (my virtual machine and web site are both dead in the water right now, as are some SQL databases)

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't look to me like an outage, error persists for a couple of hours now and website is down.

Comment: You can visit the [website](http://www.levhm.com) to see out yourself.

Comment: Hmm.  Just spitballing here, but if it's a nuget package, go to the root of your solution (in folder browser, not in VS), find the 'packages' directory, blast it.  This should force VS to update the nuget packages / replace manifests and everything

Comment: Please read my update. But that Owin thing is something not mentioned in my entire solution (since the rollback) even once. Besides it does the name of the old project in the StackTrace, this project doesn't exist in the current changeset at all!

Comment: ahhhh ok, I had misunderstood, I thought Owin was part of both the current and old (removed) project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to the help of [David Ebbo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/david%20ebbo/?ws=usercard-mini) of  Microsoft, I've discovered in an [msdn thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/59b82c2f-c368-4fca-be1d-68f745b854c3/tfs-azure-website-is-down-error-persists-after-rollback#5757b039-9097-4167-a5fc-2ebaba4967b7) about this awesome tool [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki), which is something you must know about if you use Azure.

With the the aid of Kudu I've been able to browse the files and discover the the folder was polluted with files from previous builds - just what I suspected.
After clearing the contents of *wwwroot* folder and redeploying again issue is gone.

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved!  I'll have to bookmark that tool and take a look at it later

Comment: Thanks for your effort Justin!